# Can you create powerpoint presentations that will be disabled/unreadable/expire after 6 months

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to be able to email out powerpoint presentation that will be disabled/unreadable/expire after 6 months. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with Rights Management, but this is not programming-related. You just need to sign up for the service (and pay for it after 6 months). Or maybe your company has this service. Works for sure in PowerPoint 2007 and 2010, I'm not sure about earlier versions.

Comment: +1 + should be closed as not related to programming.

Comment: thanks otaku. i just tried to find what you suggest on google/MS IRM pages, but can't find the time expiry option. can you send me a link to a page?

Comment: no problem. You can find more details at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA101029181033.aspx#Expire

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you could do is to embed the presentation in a winforms application with an ActiveX Control, which you set to not run after a certain length of time.

If you are not a programmer, I'm sorry; this is a site for programming-related questions, so I made some assumptions.

Comment: thanks jay. no, i'm not a programmer. do you know who i can pay to do something like what you have suggested?

Comment: Try elance.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do as suggested by another, the Information Right Management and it works well. My company has this service, so I don't need to sign up with my hotmail.com